# Solving for a vector, $x,$ in $\mathbb R^3$ given by its image and other vectors in $\mathbb R^2.$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $2 \times 3$ matrix and $v_1,v_2$, and $x$ be vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ such that;

Where $(a,b)$ is given as a coefficient vector in $\mathbb R^2 $

$$A(x) = (-5,9)$$
$$A(v_1) = (3,2)$$
$$A(v_2) = (2,3)$$

Solve for $x$ in terms of $v_1$ and $v_2$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I know that the transformed vectors A(v1) and A(v2) are a linear combination of the vector A(x), which I can solve for because (3,2) and (2,3) span R^2. But I'm not sure how to relate that back to the non-transformed vectors.